# Scripted Importer 'Cannot add a null object: test

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a 'Heightmap' class that I am writing, it's intended to be saved to file, both for 'preset' maps in Unity as well as being saved and loaded during runtime. The runtime side works fine as the map can be both loaded and saved, but while working on the ScriptedImporter for it it throws the error

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot add a null object: filename
> UnityEditor.AssetImporters.AssetImportContext.AddObjectToAsset(System.String identifier, UnityEngine.Object obj)

Here is the Heightmap class

```cs
using System.IO;
using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Aurora.TerrainTools
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a heightmap for terrain generation and manipulation.
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    public class Heightmap : UnityEngine.Object
    {
        #region Constants

        private const ushort SOI = 0x0315;
        private const ushort EOI = 0x0804;

        #endregion

        #region Fields

        private readonly int m_Width;
        private readonly int m_Height;
        private readonly float [] m_Data;

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the width of the heightmap.
        /// </summary>
        public int Width => m_Width;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the height of the heightmap.
        /// </summary>
        public int Height => m_Height;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the heightmap value at the specified coordinates.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">The x-coordinate.</param>
        /// <param name="y">The y-coordinate.</param>
        /// <returns>The heightmap value at the specified coordinates.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">Thrown when coordinates are out of map range.</exception>
        public float this [ int x, int y ]
        {
            get
            {
                if ( !InMapRange ( x, y ) )
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ( "coordinates" );
                return m_Data [ x + ( y * m_Width ) ];
            }

            set
            {
                if ( !InMapRange ( x, y ) )
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ( "coordinates" );
                m_Data [ x + ( y * m_Width ) ] = value;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the Heightmap class with the specified dimensions.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="width">The width of the heightmap.</param>
        /// <param name="height">The height of the heightmap.</param>
        public Heightmap ( int width, int height )
        {
            m_Width = width;
            m_Height = height;
            m_Data = new float [ width * height ];
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the Heightmap class by loading data from a stream.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stream">The stream containing heightmap data.</param>
        /// <exception cref="IOException">Thrown if the heightmap data is invalid or loading fails.</exception>
        public Heightmap ( Stream stream )
        {
            using ( BinaryReader reader = new ( stream ) )
            {
                try
                {
                    if ( reader.ReadUInt16 () == SOI )
                    {
                        m_Width = reader.ReadInt32 ();
                        m_Height = reader.ReadInt32 ();

                        m_Data = new float [ m_Width * m_Height ];

                        for ( int i = 0; i < m_Data.Length; i++ )
                        {
                            m_Data [ i ] = reader.ReadSingle ();
                        }

                        if ( reader.ReadUInt16 () != EOI )
                        {
                            throw new IOException ( "Invalid heightmap" );
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new IOException ( "Invalid heightmap" );
                    }
                }
                catch ( Exception e )
                {
                    string message = $"Error loading heightmap: {e.Message}";
                    Debug.LogError ( message );

                    throw new IOException ( message );
                }

                Debug.Log ( "Success in loading, why is it null" );
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if the given coordinates are within the map range.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">The x-coordinate.</param>
        /// <param name="y">The y-coordinate.</param>
        /// <returns><c>true</c> if the coordinates are within the map range, otherwise <c>false</c>.</returns>
        public bool InMapRange ( int x, int y ) => x >= 0 && x < m_Width && y >= 0 && y < m_Height;

        /// <summary>
        /// Saves the heightmap data to a stream.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stream">The stream to save the heightmap data to.</param>
        public void Save ( Stream stream )
        {
            using ( BinaryWriter writer = new ( stream ) )
            {
                try
                {
                    writer.Write ( SOI ); // Start of Image (SOI)
                    writer.Write ( m_Width );
                    writer.Write ( m_Height );

                    foreach ( float i in m_Data )
                    {
                        writer.Write ( i );
                    }

                    writer.Write ( EOI ); // End of Image (EOI)
                }
                catch ( Exception e )
                {
                    Debug.LogError ( "Error saving heightmap: " + e.Message );
                }
            }
        }

        public void Normalize () => Normalize ( 0, 1 );

        public void Normalize ( float minHeight, float maxHeight )
        {
            float minValue = float.MaxValue;
            float maxValue = float.MinValue;

            for ( int i = 0; i < m_Data.Length; i++ )
            {
                minValue = Mathf.Min ( minValue, m_Data [ i ] );
                maxValue = Mathf.Max ( maxValue, m_Data [ i ] );
            }

            for ( int i = 0; i < m_Data.Length; i++ )
            {
                m_Data [ i ] = Mathf.Lerp ( minHeight, maxHeight, Mathf.InverseLerp ( minValue, maxValue, m_Data [ i ] ) );
            }
        }

        public void NormalizeToInt ( int minHeight, int maxHeight )
        {
            float minValue = float.MaxValue;
            float maxValue = float.MinValue;

            for ( int i = 0; i < m_Data.Length; i++ )
            {
                minValue = Mathf.Min ( minValue, m_Data [ i ] );
                maxValue = Mathf.Max ( maxValue, m_Data [ i ] );
            }

            for ( int i = 0; i < m_Data.Length; i++ )
            {
                m_Data [ i ] = Mathf.Round ( Mathf.Lerp ( minHeight, maxHeight, Mathf.InverseLerp ( minValue, maxValue, m_Data [ i ] ) ) );
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

and the Importer

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using UnityEditor.AssetImporters;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Aurora.TerrainTools.Editor
{
    [ScriptedImporter ( 1, "heightmap", AllowCaching = true )]
    public class HeightmapImporter : ScriptedImporter
    {
        [SerializeField, HideInInspector] private Heightmap m_Heightmap;

        public override void OnImportAsset ( AssetImportContext ctx )
        {
            using ( FileStream stream = new FileStream ( ctx.assetPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read ) )
            {
                m_Heightmap = new Heightmap ( stream );
                ctx.AddObjectToAsset ( Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension ( ctx.assetPath ), m_Heightmap );
                ctx.SetMainObject ( m_Heightmap );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I can determine it should be working, but it isn't.

Comment: Another thing I just noted: read-only fields and properties are not serialized in Unity ... even if you would create the asset and save it .. all the fields will be uninitialized after deserialization!

Comment: It's serialization and deserialization isn't handled by Unity, so it actually doesn't get uninitialized

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which tutorial you read or which one you came up with, but AFAIK inheriting directly from the `Object` class does not work. If you want to create and instantiate a custom class, it should inherit from the [`ScriptableObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.html) class and be instantiated using the [`CreateInstance`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.CreateInstance.html) method. The `Serializable` attribute isn't necessary, and you can't use constructors, you can define some `Init` methods instead.

```
public class Heightmap : ScriptableObject

...

m_Heightmap = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Heightmap>();
m_Heightmap.Init(stream);
```

Comment: The last time that I attempted to write a ScriptedImporter for a ScriptableObject it flat out refused to work (The importer itself worked, but the 'Object Field' would not 'accept' it), I'm not sure what happened, but I'm glad it's working now. Thank you.

Comment: The only remaining thing is that a user should be permitted (without warnings or errors) to simply 'create' a new instance of it (like how you can simply create a new texture or mesh)

Comment: What warnings or errors?

Comment: The ones stating that you have to use the 'CreateInstance' method

Comment: @RWolfe **how** did you try to create instances? `new` is not allowed for `ScriptableObject`. In code you use `CreateInstance` .. just like e.g. for `Sprite` you have to use `Sprite.Create` .. it is like that because under the hood the instance is not created by the `c#` layer but the underlaying `c++` engine and the `c#` layer only an interface on top of it ... Why it is so inconsistent between the different Unity built-in types I can't tell you .. we just have to live with it the way it is ;)

Comment: @RWolfe, this is what Unity asks, and it is simple. I don't quite understand why you need to permit a user to create this height map through programming. If you are designing a plugin, Unity also provides [CreateAssetMenuAttribute](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CreateAssetMenuAttribute.html) to create instances through the menu.

Comment: the type I'm creating is intended to function a lot like a Texture, with a singular 'channel', you don't create a texture in Unity by clicking 'Assets > Create > Texture', you create it in code, and can then save it to a file, this is what I'm trying to do, you can't change the content of the texture in the inspector either

Comment: @derHugo I am aware that `new` is not allowed for ScriptableObject. I was hoping to bypass that so that a user could simply call `new Heightmap(...)` without the warnings that this is not permitted. The classes behavior is supposed to be similar to that of how creating and saving textures works

Comment: @RWolfe I don't think you can. Afaik (as mentioned before) the type needs to be a Unity known asset type (or subtype of one) like e.g. ScriptableObject in your case and for those you can only use a constructor (and `new`) in case the standard API provides such .. if the API requires other ways of creating the instances so do you .. you **can** of course always create a wrapper type that creates the scriptableobject instance in the constructor and use implicit conversions between them to make it easy for the users